# Cocoa cannot access array element after first index?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Why is this crashing?

```
NSArray *domain = [webView.request.URL.absoluteString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *str1 = [domain objectAtIndex:2];
```

This is the error I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

I am able to use objectAtIndex:0 just fine.

Comment: This is not C++, by any standard.

Comment: @All: Regarding the 2. question, please ignore it and don't start any flamewars. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error talks about an array with *zero* elements. The one you're thinking about contains more than zero elements. Are you sure you're looking at the right thing? Also, if you're calling that code more than one time, it might be the case that once it uses one value, and another on the next run.

Put a breakpoint at that line and see what the value of `domain` is on each iteration.

Comment: Ok let's say the array has no elements, how do I prevent it from crashing then? How can I check if the element exists first and proceed if it does?

Comment: @user969622, use `NSArray`'s [`count()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) method to see if the array is empty or not, or to see if the index you're looking for does indeed exist (if it's higher than the total number of elements, then, of course, it does not exist). For future reference, take a look at the class documentation and look at the "Tasks" category. You'll find the supported methods categorized by their purpose.

Comment: I tried `NSMutableArray *domain = [webView.request.URL.absoluteString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
  
  
  NSInteger *count = [domain count];` but it is crashing after the last line

Comment: @user969622, no problem. Do check the documentation, it's very well written and indexed.

Comment: @user969622: `NSInteger` is not the same of a class, and `-[NSArray count]` returns an `NSUInteger`, not a pointer to an `NSInteger`. So, you need to declare the `count` variable as `NSUInteger count`, with the `U` and without the `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Insert `NSLog(@"%@",domain);` between those lines, and see what you're actually getting in the array.  It sounds like there's on slash in the string you're splitting, which would give you two elements.  NSArray indices are zero-based, just like C arrays.

> why is Cocoa such a god damn pain in the *?

Are you just stumbling around and trying to teach yourself by trial and error, or have you taken the time to work through any of the tutorials?

Comment: This is what I am getting:

    `"http:",
    "",
    "www.google.com",
    "?q=test"`

Trial and error, and also searching through tutorials. Didn't think it would be this complicated. I am writing several lines of code to do something I would normally do in one line...

Comment: @user969622, it's common for users of completely new programming languages that they've never even seen before to write several lines of code to do something they would normally do in one line with the a language they know. With practice, that will change.

Comment: If that is what you are seeing in the log, then objectAtIndex:2 would work fine. Is there some other code between creating the array and accessing it?